# Unit test on Redis with Flask and Pytest

Tags: python, flask, redis, pytest

I have a problem with my unit tests via pytest.

To contextualize I try to test the addition and presence of data on my Redis.

For my interactions with redis I use this:
https://github.com/underyx/flask-redis/blob/master/flask_redis/client.py

My tests look like this:

```
sample_key = b"-vmbFSk5WRKwnIRIkBLWtEd5g9Hqy3IO67Bmdnqf2Ek="
user_uuid = "8bb739e5-cf44-4e87-b1f7-b8eb1cc6c25d"


def test_check_already_connected():
    assert check_already_connected(user_uuid) is False
    RedisWrapper.set(sample_key, '3', user_uuid)


def test_check_already_connected1():
    RedisWrapper.set(sample_key, '3', user_uuid)
    print("keys")
    print(RedisWrapper.get_all_keys())
    assert check_already_connected(user_uuid) is True
```

This is what I get when I run my tests:

```
tests/test_authentication.py Error -  the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
.Error -  the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
keys
[]
F

============================================= FAILURES =============================================
__________________________________ test_check_already_connected1 ___________________________________

    def test_check_already_connected1():
        RedisWrapper.set(sample_key, '3', user_uuid)
        print("keys")
        print(RedisWrapper.get_all_keys())
>       assert check_already_connected(user_uuid) is True
E       AssertionError: assert False is True
E        +  where False = check_already_connected('8bb739e5-cf44-4e87-b1f7-b8eb1cc6c25d')

tests/test_authentication.py:26: AssertionError
=================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.42s ====================================
```

My wrapper for redis:
https://textup.fr/435412an

Initializing redis_client in app/***init***.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
redis_client = FlaskRedis(app)
```

The function I want to test:

```
def check_already_connected(user_uuid):
    redis_keys = RedisWrapper.get_all_keys()
    if redis_keys:
        for key in redis_keys:
            entry = RedisWrapper.get(key)
            account_uuid = entry.get('3')
            if account_uuid == str(user_uuid):
                return True
    return False
```

I guess the problem is the initialization of Redis before my tests but I tested several solutions without success.

Comment: is RedisWrapper mock or actual implementation ?

Comment: Current implementation, I don't use a mock.

Comment: Then it is not unit testing but integration testing.  While unit testing an external system, you have to mock it(isolate) not directly calling actual implementation.

Comment: Ah okay, so the data storage verification is obviously a test of integration.

So I have to simulate the stored data and just check how my code works in different cases?

Comment: exactly, redis or the library already has unit tests, what you will need to do is isolate it(if there is an interface it will be easier) and pretend you are executing the redis commands via using your mock.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it will save me from wasting more time doing something that doesn't fit!

Comment: You are welcome, i am not familiar with python but you will probably find some resources to do it easily. Good luck.